# Magento 1.9.2.4 download file size is very large 424MB? where is Magento 1.9.2.1?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to download Magento 1.9.2.4 but it's file size is very huge approx 424MB. I have previously worked on Magento 1.9.2.1. It was only less than 100MB in file size, Now i am unable to find this version on Magento website and Magento 1.9.2.1 version was not big as the new version. So, my question is,  am i downloading correct file which is (Magento 1.9.2.4)?

Why there is huge difference of size between Magento 1.9.2.4(424MB) and Magento 1.9.2.1(Less than 100 MB)

Where should i download Magento 1.9.2.1?

[image]

Comment: you are downloading sample data not magento source code

Comment: Ya  "faizanbeg" is right. you need to download magento without source code. if file size is large for you.

Comment: Where is the source code? I am unable to find it on Magento Website.

Comment: below this on same page find ver 1.9.x on the same page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find ver 1.9.x on the this page
[this](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download)

Then goto **Release Archive** tab,then goto text **ver 1.9.x** here you find, all 1.9.x version

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: download  1.9.3.1 latest version